# VS Code C++ Parameter Autocomplete

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, with the C++ extension, is there any way I can get the parameter names for functions to be filled out automatically after e.g. selecting a function name suggested by intellisense? The parameters should then be filled out as if they were a snippet. This feature is common in several IDEs, such as Eclipse.

Comment: If you want IDE, just use an IDE. Don't try hard to make an IDE from an Editor.

Comment: you get a tooltip of the known function arguments, for a skilled C++ programmer that is enough reminder

Comment: Honestly mind-blown by both these comments. The core idea behind VS code is extensibility. Telling me not to "try hard to make an IDE from an Editor" is like telling someone not to use VS extensions. If autocomplete is an "IDE feature" what about Intellisense? Or git integration? Or debugging tools? The beauty of VS Code is its flexibility . Not to mention that this feature is implemented in other languages **within** VSC. And for the second comment - I'm dumbfounded. "Skilled" programmers don't need any help from their IDE (sorry, *editor)? Sheesh. I need to get off SO. Time for a drink.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a perfectly valid question and nothing to do with IDE-like features as some are suggesting in the comments.

Short answer is **No**.
VS Code's C/C++ extension will not expand the autocompletion feature to the argument list of a function.

The more involved answer is that the authors of the C/C++ extension could do so but for some reason (probably a good one) have chosen not to.

The autocomplete feature is actually handled by the Language Server for C/C++. A Language Server is an implementation of the [Language Server Protocol  (LSP)](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) which is simply a way to provide programming language-specific features for multiple code editors / IDEs.

The LSP, **written by Microsoft originally for VSCode**, absolutely permits such types of completion. After all, that is how snippets are handled. If you have a look at LSP's [specification page](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specifications/specification-3-17/#completionItem) you will see this bit
[image]

`insertText` is just a string so theoretically the server could pass the function name + argument list in the format of a snippet, set the variable `InsertTextFormat == 2`, marking it as a snippet and then pressing `Tab` would autocomplete to exactly what you want.

Here is an example of how it looks like (implemented in our [Fortran language server](https://github.com/gnikit/fortls))

[image]

You might want to open a feature request/ask the question in their [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues). They will probably have a better answer as to why it is the way it is. If I had to guess I would say that it is related to overloading.